# Using PySide in a buildout environment

Tags: python, pyside, buildout

I'm currently trying to find a good solution in order to use PySide in a zc.buildout.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a good recipe combination to build/install PySide inside a zc.buildout. The solutions and recipes I've tried so far, do either not:

- set the path to look up the shared librarys, e.g. `rpath`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- don't run the `pyside_postinstall.py` script, which sets the correct `rpath` to lookup the shared libraries
- the environment fails to provide me a path variable which I can pass to some recipes to run the `pyside_postinstall.py`

The only way to make it work is to simply install it with easy_install in your virtualenv. That's great, but I'm interested if I can do it in buildout. Perhaps there is no other way than creating a new recipe :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question: All you need are two parts in your buildout:

```
[buildout]
parts = pyside-interpreter
        pyside-postinstall

[pyside-interpreter] 
recipe = zc.recipe.egg 
interpreter = pyside-python
eggs = PySide

[pyside-postinstall] 
recipe = plone.recipe.command
command = ${buildout:directory}/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

Keep PySide as a dependency as usual. The first part simply creates all PySide scripts, including the `pyside_postinstall.py`. The second part simply executes the script and writes the `rpath`. All further scripts which need PySide by can simply import it as usual. **Mind the order**, which is important if you add more parts.

Thanks to the user [rlacko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052118/rlacko) and his initial [pyside-buildout](https://github.com/PySide/pyside-buildout) project, which lead me to two new options in buildout and it's recipes:

- `zc.recipe.egg` option to set the interpreter, will create PySides postinstall script
- `zc.buildout` also provides a `setup` option, which allows to run a setup script.

**Update:** On some Linux distributions (and Windows) you'll need to compile PySide manually and point it to qmake. Use the extra steps from the [pyside-buildout](https://github.com/PySide/pyside-buildout) project.

Comment: It should be noted that this will compile the egg without pyside specific parameters. For example on Windows (and also on Ubuntu 13.04) you need to explicitli specify the path to qmake via --qmake parameter when compiling the egg. To set additional parameters you need two extra steps (pyside-download and pyside-bdist-egg) that can be found in the pyside-buildout project.

Comment: You're right, some distributions use a different name for qmake. I simply linked it to the right version, thats why it didn't fall on my feet.

Comment: also i forgot to mention that the pyside-postinstall part is not needed on Windows platform, since PySide version 1.2.0 the configuration is done at runtime when PySide module is imported, Thanks, -Roman

Answer (score 1):

I have created the [pyside-buildout](https://github.com/PySide/pyside-buildout) project which downloads, builds distributions egg and configures pyside so it is instaled and available in buildout's eggs directory.

It was tested on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) and Windows 7 64bit.

It's recommended to use latest version of virtualenv.

Comment: Ohm... how is that different to simply installing PySide inside your virtualenv?

Comment: there is no difference, but it's handled by your buildout so it's more comfortable than manually installing.

Comment: @romanofski i will provide you better example that will install pyside to buildout eggs, please stay tuned

Comment: When following the steps on this project, it already fails during bootstrap.py: `Error: The specified download cache: /tmp/pyside-buildout/downloads Doesn't exist`. Besides, I very much appreciate you creating a new project for this, but I don't want to use SE as an issue tracker. Perhaps the answer to my question is *no* and the solution is to creating a special recipe.

Comment: One further problem on trying the buildout is, that it compiles and installs PySide twice. First it installs PySide, that it installs the interpreter and compiles again. This is not a portable solution.

Comment: Regarding to not existing downloads folder, you need to create the folder before calling bootstrap and this is described in README.rst. The PySide egg is compiled only once, the trick is that the comiled egg is located in downloads/dist folder so buildout can find the egg when installing pyside-interpreter part (it does not trying to compile it again). It seems you have not following the instruction in README.rst ?